# implementation of a c++ counter for inherited classes that is visible in default constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

so i've tried multiple ways of creating a counter for my class that's passing the number in the constructor

i want it to output something like this:

```
input the amount of base class objects: 2
The A# 1:
input SomeVar_one: 3
input SomeVar_two: 2
The A# 2:
input SomeVar_one: 2
input SomeVar_two: 3
input the amount of derived class objects: 2
The A# 1:
input SomeVar_one: 23
input SomeVar_two: 32
The A# 2:
input SomeVar_one: 12
input SomeVar_two: 42
total # of base objects is: 4
total # of derived objects is: 4
```

where i do get this:

```
input the amount of base class objects: 2
The A# 1:
input SomeVar_one: 3
input SomeVar_two: 2
The A# 2:
input SomeVar_one: 2
input SomeVar_two: 3
input the amount of derived class objects: 2
The A# 3:
input SomeVar_one: 23
input SomeVar_two: 32
The A# 4:
input SomeVar_one: 12
input SomeVar_two: 42
total # of base objects is: 4
total # of derived objects is: 4
```

notice the difference between the user prompts for inputting the values that is called from the constructor that is called from the `new` operator

ofc there is a need to give them their separate names and this is a question that i'd like to adress as well. anything you might suggest is acceptable.

the main goal is to instantiate objects right at the moment when the `new` operator is called without getting in the `for` loop at which i ofc can call `"The (A/B) # (i)"`

here is a code that i've used: it uses the "curiously recurring template pattern" (btw this name is a killer!)

```
//sample
#include<iostream>
template <typename T>
class counter
{
public:
    counter(bool do_count = true) : counted(do_count)
    {
        if (counted) get_count()++;
    }
    ~counter()
    {
        if (counted) get_count()--;
    }
    static unsigned long GetInstancesCount()
    {
        return get_count();
    }

private:
    bool counted;
    static unsigned long& get_count()
    {
        static unsigned long count = 0;
        return count;
    }
};


class base:public counter<base>
{
protected:
    int m_SomeVar_one = 0, m_SomeVar_two = 0;
    unsigned long ObjectNumber = 0;
public: 
    base(bool count=true):counter<base>(count),ObjectNumber(counter<base>::GetInstancesCount())
    {
        std::cout << "The A# " << ObjectNumber <<": " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "input SomeVar_one: ";
        std::cin >> m_SomeVar_one;
        std::cout << "input SomeVar_two: ";
        std::cin >> m_SomeVar_two;
    }
    virtual int get_count()
    {
        return counter<base>::GetInstancesCount();
    }
};

class derived :public base, public counter<derived>
{
protected:
    int m_SomeVar_three = 0;

public:
    derived(bool count = true) :base(false), counter<derived>(count)
    {
        std::cout << "input SomeVar_three: ";
        std::cin >> m_SomeVar_three;
    }
    virtual int get_count() override
    {
        return counter<derived>::GetInstancesCount();
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "input the amount of base class objects: ";
    int amountOfBaseObjects;
    std::cin >> amountOfBaseObjects;
    base* BaseArray = new base[amountOfBaseObjects];


    std::cout << "input the amount of derived class objects: ";
    int amountOfDerivedObjects;
    std::cin >> amountOfDerivedObjects;
    base* DerivedArray = new base[amountOfDerivedObjects];

    std::cout <<"total # of base objects is: "<< BaseArray->get_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "total # of derived objects is: " << DerivedArray->get_count() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: So to be clear here, you want your `counter` class to keep a separate counter for each type that inherits it instead of one count for all `counter` types? Have you tried using a static `map` of string typenames to int counts?

Comment: yes i want and i really do not know about the map of string typenames(( i'm still lerning it all by myself!

Comment: there has to be a counter for each specific object, and i still think it's more of a class and constructor design question, for how can it output different object numbers for different types, while still preventing code duplication

Comment: but if there is such thing as self-enlarging map that'll be giving new typenames based on new classes that i could create then it's great!!

Comment: @pohaha The way you're doing it now, using a static local inside a template to generate a counter for each type, is both perfectly valid and doesn't require RTTI. I'd stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

CRTP doesn't really gel well with virtual polymorphism - virtual polymorphism involves a common base class, while CRTP generates a different base class for each derived type.

Anyway, you can crack it with composition. Here is a non-template version of counter with a factory method template. Note the rule of 3 is necessary to do accurate reference counting:

```cpp
class counter
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    static counter create()
    {
        static unsigned long count = 0;
        return { &count };
    }
    counter(const counter& that) : count_addr(that.count_addr)
    {
        (*count_addr)++;
    }
    counter& operator =(const counter& that)
    {
        (*count_addr)--;
        count_addr = that.count_addr;
        (*count_addr)++;
        return *this;
    }
    ~counter()
    {
        (*count_addr)--;
    }
    unsigned long GetInstancesCount()
    {
        return *count_addr;
    }

private:
    unsigned long* count_addr;
    counter(unsigned long* count_addr) : count_addr(count_addr)
    {
        (*count_addr)++;
    }
};
```

Then you can embed a counter as a member of the base class, with the option for a derived class to provide its own counter via a protected constructor. The bit where the public constructors forward a factory method instead of a counter is to ensure there are no living temporary copies, which could could accidentally inflate the count, when `ObjectNumber` is assigned.

```cpp
class base
{
public: 
    base() : base(counter::create<base>)
    {
    }
    int get_count()
    {
        return ctr.GetInstancesCount();
    }
private:
    counter ctr;
protected:
    base(counter(*ctr)()) : ctr(ctr()), ObjectNumber(this->ctr.GetInstancesCount())
    {
        std::cout << "The A# " << ObjectNumber <<": " << std::endl;
    }
    unsigned long ObjectNumber; // important - must come after counter
};

class derived : public base
{
public:
    derived() : base(counter::create<derived>)
    {
    }
};
```

After that, I can roughly replicate your intended output: https://godbolt.org/z/eonfb9

Comment: So first of all thank you very much for helping, and  now can you suggest some good literature about factory pattern, YouTube lectures would even be better!! But secondly, it still does not do what I wanted, because I want to call a constructor via new operator which will be telling that it “creates the object of type (x) number (object number)”. While they are sharing data in a continuous manner -((data1-data2)-data3) I need toinstantiate base class data via a base class constructor and add a little bit extra via a derived class constructor

Comment: but the information message about type of object and it’s number is displayed first! So it has to be displayed in the base class constructor, which in turn calls for a base class object number, which I do not want while creating a derived class

Comment: "factory" is barely a pattern. Any time you use a function that returns an object instead of a constructor, that's just the name for it. Reasons you might want that are you need a named constructor, or in this case, you need a constructor with an explicit template.

Comment: The other things you're asking for are pretty trivial to add. You can add members and constructor parameters to your base and derived classes as you please, this doesn't really interfere with that. The only way to get the name at runtime for logging is with the `<typeinfo>` header, but it's implementation defined and not guaranteed to be unique or readable. [here](https://godbolt.org/z/baoxdz) is how you might extend it to add a name to the counter and output the specific text you want. But you might have better control by adding a static member to the class with the name.

Comment: Man you’ve broadened my horizons. Thanks a lot. Didn’t think about creating a constructor with a value returned from function! It is really nice. I’lol look into this factory pattern(or not pattern) closely think i’ll learn something new. Now the only question is how can I point that this question is answered?